# Блокировка доступа к странице

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы если **Пользователь 1** занес **Пользователя 2** в черный список, то при переходе **Пользователем 2** на страницу **Пользователя 1**  показывалось отдельное сообщение.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что-то вроде   

    if (in_array($userlogin2, $blacklist1)) die ("You in blacklist");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query('select * from `user_ban_table` where `user_id`='.$user1Id.' and `ban_id`='.$user2Id);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
  print('Отдельное сообщение');
};
```

Таблица:

```
user_id | ban_id
```